# How do I NOT reduce loop integrals to one-point in FeynCalc?

Tags: feyncalc

So I am doing a box integral, the amplitudes look like this:

[image: Amplitude]

I do the loop integration of it using the following code:

`(TID[#1, q, ToPaVe->True, UsePaVeBasis->True,]&)[ChangeDimension[amp[1],D]]`

where `amp[1]` is the amplitude I just defined. But whenever I do this I get my final result in terms of `A0` functions, how do I change this so that I only get `D0` and `D00` functions??

Comment: Please post your code as text, not images. See [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/27951).Make sure to include all relevant definitions as well, so your code can be executed.

Comment: I second MarcoB's request. Evaluating `amp//StandardForm` and copying the input is actually waaay more easier that posting pictures...

Answer (score 2):

You can disable partial fractioning (which is what reducing your denominator to `A0`), but most likely you will need to do it on a case-by-case basis

```
amp = SpinorUBar[p3] . GA[rho, mu, 7] . SpinorU[p] SpinorUBar[p1] . 
    GA[mu, rho, 6] . 
    SpinorV[p2] FAD[{q, mk}, {q, ml}, {q, mZ}, {q, mW}] +
  0 SpinorUBar[p3] . GA[rho] . GS[q] . GA[rho, 7] . 
    SpinorU[p] SpinorUBar[p1] . GA[mu] . GS[q] . GA[rho, 6] . 
    SpinorV[p2] FAD[{q, mk}, {q, ml}, {q, mZ}, {q, mW}]
```

```
TID[ChangeDimension[amp, D], q, ToPaVe -> True, UsePaVeBasis -> True, 
   ApartFF -> False] // FCE // StandardForm
(*
I \[Pi]^2 D0[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, mk^2, ml^2, mW^2, 
  mZ^2] Spinor[Momentum[p1, D], 0, 1] . GAD[mu] . GAD[rho] . GA[6] . 
  Spinor[-Momentum[p2, D], 0, 1] Spinor[Momentum[p3, D], 0, 1] . 
  GAD[rho] . GAD[mu] . GA[7] . Spinor[Momentum[p, D], 0, 1]
*)
```

If it is about numerical stability, I'd rather convert `A0`'s to `B0`'s

```
res = TID[ChangeDimension[amp, D], q, ToPaVe -> True, 
  UsePaVeBasis -> True]
res /. A0[x_] :> A0[x, A0ToB0 -> True]
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so very much! I will do consider @MarcoB and your suggestions for any future questions.